# "Secmod module already configured" in applet when reloading

Tags: java, https, applet, certificate

I'm modifying a signed applet which uses a user certificate to connect to a servlet and then confirms some information of the user (his name is the alias. It is an official certificate).

It basically uses getLocalCertificates() (after connecting) and in Explorer it works fine returning the alias and connecting to the SSL secured servlet and returning the information about the user. In Firefox (and Chrome, and Safari...) it returns null as alias, and it returns a 403.

So I've implemented a setSSLSocketFactory() system for Firefox based on loading the certificates in the local NSS database.

This is the error I get in Firefox's Java Console.

I get this error:

```
·· _pk11provider 
      _pk11provider Secmod module already configured
  ·· Set keyStore: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: missing provider
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.cmt.applets.notif.AppletNotif.setMozillaKeyStore(AppletNotif.java:1635)
    at com.cmt.applets.notif.AppletNotif.setAlias(AppletNotif.java:1404)
    at com.cmt.applets.notif.AppletNotif.init(AppletNotif.java:223)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: missing provider
```

The code for Firefox (at this moment only for Windows) is

[...]

```
String userProfile = Mozilla.getMozillaUserProfileDirectory();

// Define provider
String providerConfig = "name = NSS" + "\n" + "nssLibraryDirectory = "
        + dir + "\n" + "nssSecmodDirectory = \"" + userProfile + "\"\n"
        + "nssDbMode = readOnly" + "\n" + "nssModule = keystore" + "\n"
        + "\r";

// Load Firefox Dlls
Mozilla.loadDll(dir);

ByteArrayInputStream localByteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
        providerConfig.getBytes());

SunPKCS11 pk11provider = null;

System.out.println("  ·· _pk11provider ");
try {

    pk11provider = new SunPKCS11(localByteArrayInputStream);
    System.out.println("    ·· addProvider(_pk11provider) ");
    Security.addProvider(pk11provider);
    System.out.println("    ·· _pk11provider.login ");
    pk11provider.login(new Subject(), new DialogCallbackHandler());
//} catch (Throwable e) {
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("      _pk11provider " + e.getMessage());
}

// Set keyStore using PKCS11 (for NSS Firefox)
System.out.println("  ·· Set keyStore: ");

try {
    keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", pk11provider);
} catch (KeyStoreException e) {
    System.out.println("   Exception en keyStore.getInstance");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("    ·· Load keystore");

try {
    keyStore.load(localByteArrayInputStream, null);
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    System.out.println("   NoSuchAlgorithmException en keyStore.load(). ");
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (CertificateException e) {
    System.out.println("   CertificateException en keyStore.load(). ");
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("   IOException en keyStore.load(). ");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("localByteArrayInputStream.close() ");
try { 
    localByteArrayInputStream.close(); 
} catch(final Exception e) 
{ 
    System.out.println("localByteArrayInputStream.close() " + e.getMessage());
}
```

[...]

This code is being called from Applet.init() ... so it should be called only the first time. It works... once. If I reload in the same Firefox tab the applet, I get the "Missing provider" error due to the "Secmod module already configured"

Searching for "Secmod module already configured" in Google and Bing I get the original java library sourcecode for SunPKCS11.java :

```
if (nssModule.hasInitializedProvider()) {
    throw new ProviderException(
        "Secmod module already configured");
}
```

Which seems contradictory with the error "Missing provider"...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it with quite an easy solution...

I made SunPKCS11 pk11provider = null a private static global variable. Then I only initialize if it is null. Yes, it is ugly to use a global variable, but it works.